# HTML <SELECT> items container border in IE10

Tags: html, select, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to change odd looks and feel of HTML dropdown component in IE10. After click the dropdown arrow the list item container come above with dark border around that I want to modify. Is it possible to control css of that part of html dropdown?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123772/black-border-when-drop-down-menu-is-open-ie-10

Answer (score 2):

It isn’t possible to change the style of the menu that holds the select items, as far as I can find. There are numerous pseudo element selectors for styling HTML controls [0] but none of them are for that menu. You can style the disclosure widget and the text of the currently selected item.

[0] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767361.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the focus outline? Most browsers will put a dotted line around an input element when it received focus. You can set `outline: none;` on your `<select>` to disable that.