# Black border when drop down menu is open - IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, select

I have built a drop down menu and I customised the down arrow.

That 's ok and working.

In IE 10 , when I open the drop down I have black borders.

[image]

Is there a way to delate those or change them colour?

**CSS**

```
#contact #tabs #bord td select {
    background: url("/static/img/down-arrow.png") no-repeat right #fff;
    border:none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120%; 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -ms-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
       display: none;

 }
```

**HTML/CMS TEMPLATE**

```
 <td colspan="2">
      <div class="styleSelect">
    <select name="topic" class="desktopDropDown" style="border:none;">
                    {% with request|enquiry_topics as topics %}
                    {% for t in topics %}
                    <option value="{{t.id}}">{{t}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endwith %}
             </select>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the popup on a select box cannot be styled on any browser including IE10.

You could create a custom dropdown menu with [**this library**](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/). But you will need to add Javascript to populate form fields or perform other functions.

Comment: so do u think with JS/Jquery is achievable ? and at least even for IE10?

Comment: Not to style a default select box. But you can create your own (with custom styles) so that they appear to be normal select boxes.

Comment: Another way, that i use for quick styles is [**this example**](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) this will allow you to keep the origin select box too, but will still have the border on the popup.

Comment: I'm gonna go for JS/Jquery solution - a bit long cos need to change template but I got exactly what I want . :) Cheers

Comment: There s a problem I didn't consider : how can handle my form for backend ? can' give name="myform" to UL tag neither value="myvalue" to LI tag

Comment: I find this other library - specific for form but when I test it in IE ...the pop up still does have black border LOL

Comment: It would be easiest to use [This style](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) with Django. Otherwise is going to be quite a bit of work. I'll update my answer in a sec with an alternative.

Comment: yea but I d have still the border problem - wouldn't I?

Comment: Yeah you would, to be honest i'm not sure there is any easy way to add this in with Django. You could look at [**form Macros**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811748/why-does-jinja-escape-html-in-a-macro). This might enable you to change elements to the layout you need.

Comment: this one may work http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ - it looks nice in IE

Answer (score 1):

try `text-decoration: none;` in your css I didn't check but it might help get rid of borders. Sometimes (for instance on  tags) IE creates borders to show it's not just plain text but interactive stuff

Answer (score 0):

not any default styling to remove black color in edge browser  .but you can achieve change custom control of dropdown  through using javascript ,jquery pluing/library